# order by number of commas

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order results from a select statement by the number of commas existing in one of the column.

is there a way to exclusively order by commas in mysql.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Does your database have comma-delimited values in a single column?

Comment: I have area codes separated by commas in this this one column, I want to count the commas because this will clearly identify quantity of entries each

Comment: And I assume that it's too late to restructure the database to be normalized?

Comment: Please fix your schema, that's the _right_ way to fix this problem. If you _ever_ find yourself having to manipulate things smaller than a column, then you've done it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order your results by the number of comma's in a specific field with a query like the  following:

```
select * from table order by length(areaCodeField)-length(replace(areaCodeField, ",", ""))) desc
```

The **order by** piece of the query will count all of the characters in the field and then subtract all of the characters not counting the commas. This leaves you with the number of commas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple workaround (that may be not very efficient):

```
ORDER BY
    LENGTH(column) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column, ',', '')) asc
```

I don't know whether other solutions exist, sorry.